# Alternative for deprecated JAXBToStringBuilder

Tags: jaxb, deprecated

We have an auto generated class which is importing the following classes:

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBToStringStyle;
```

Both of these seem to be deprecated, I am looking for an alternative, did some search but couldn't find anything similar to use for the following method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return JAXBToStringBuilder.valueOf(this, JAXBToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [javadoc for 2.7.x](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.7.x/org/apache/cxf/jaxb/JAXBToStringBuilder.html) says

> Class was moved to project org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils:cxf-xjc-runtime so generated code does not have to depend on cxf

Depending on a current cxf-xjc-runtime and changing the imports seemed to be enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons has a class called ToStringBuilder that you can introduce in your code to help representing objects as Strings in a human readable format.
See the doc [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html).

Check the constructor where you can specify the style:
    ToStringBuilder(Object object, ToStringStyle style) 
    Constructs a builder for the specified object using the a defined output style.

There you can provide to the default style you mentioned in your question:

```
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE).toString();
}
```

Comment: Since the question is about JAXB generated code: You can let JAXB generate toString methods that use Apache Commons like this using the commons-lang-plugin extension from https://github.com/javaee/jaxb2-commons